# CHROME CSS ellipses bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I dumped the files on a free hosting site, you can see the example here > http://www.justatest23.byethost24.com/

THIS IS CHOME ONLY!(its being built as an http://electron.atom.io/ app, which uses node.js locally with chromium

the problem can be recreated by shrinking the width of the page from about 900px wide to about 880px wide, when doing so, the ellipses are triggered on the bank of america example field. The problem is that when you click on the row, the color changes and then the ellipses are no longer the same color as their parent container.

QUESTION: how do you keep the ellipses the same color as their sibling characters when hovering after color change?

**Sorry, about the .less

***thanks in advance

EDIT*** Submitted an issue >> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=573395

Comment: Just managed to reproduce this. Thanks for reporting, will try and replicate my use case.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your bug. It definitely looks like a Chrome bug. You should put the demo in a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), trim it down until it only includes what is essential to reproduce the bug, and submit it here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: just submitted, thanks >> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=573395

Answer (score 0):

I tried and failed to reproduce a small test case — and [the jsbin test case produced for the Chromium bug report](http://jsbin.com/sihewubomu/4/edit?html,output) couldn't reproduce the bug on my version of Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.110 m):

```css
body {
  color: black;
}

div:before {
  content: attr( title );
  font-weight: bold;
}


.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

[title="Colour by explicit application"] 
.container .text {
  color: red;
}

[title="Colour by inheritance"]
.container {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div title="Colour by explicit application">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text">
      One April day many years ago, at a time when I still wondered about the meaning of life, I went into a little cigar store on a back street to buy a cigar. I selected a dark and square El Zelo, put it in my cigar case, paid for it, and prepared to leave. But all of a sudden it occurred to me to show the young girl, who worked in the store and from whom I usually bought my cigars, a little sketch in India ink that I happened to have in my wallet. I had gotten it from a young artist and in my opinion it was very beautiful. “Look,” I said and handed it to her. “What do you think of this?”
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div title="Colour by inheritance">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text">
      One April day many years ago, at a time when I still wondered about the meaning of life, I went into a little cigar store on a back street to buy a cigar. I selected a dark and square El Zelo, put it in my cigar case, paid for it, and prepared to leave. But all of a sudden it occurred to me to show the young girl, who worked in the store and from whom I usually bought my cigars, a little sketch in India ink that I happened to have in my wallet. I had gotten it from a young artist and in my opinion it was very beautiful. “Look,” I said and handed it to her. “What do you think of this?”
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I encountered the bug myself and [can *still* reproduce the error in the original problem case](http://www.justatest23.byethost24.com/): I expect some level of complexity and / or changes to the DOM during run time are necessary to reproduce.

I've managed to determine that in my code (and in the original problem case, via Chrome Dev Tools), I can work around the bug by ensuring the colour is *inherit* rather than applied directly to the overflown element itself. This could be avoided procedurally by nesting all ellipsis overflow text in a wrapping element and applying the colour there instead.